# HDRI scaling problem

Tags: hdri

I'm starting to work with HDRI images for lighting in blender. And I have a file that's acting a bit weird. If I open a brand new file and setup an HDRI image, and turn on the world background in Display, it looks as below:

[image]

But in my working file, if I add the exact same HDRI image with the exact same node setup, I get the following

[image]

The second case it's very zoomed in (I think), not sure exactly what settings I have that are messed up in the second case.

If I look through the camera it seems fine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Your are in orthographic projection view.

For obvious geometric reasons you cannot view a equirectangular images in orthographic views because there is no perspective to speak of, so you are looking in a single direction, viewing a theoretically infinitesimally small portion of the background image, yielding an apparently flat looking background.

Switch back to prespective view by pressing <kbd>Numpad 5</kbd>